# First time upload laravel project to cpanel but always error

Tags: php, laravel

Help I got this problem when uploading my first laravel project to cpanel, can anyone help me. I've tried clear cache but it did not work

The error code is:

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:185
```

and the other error code hinted is:

```
ErrorException file_put_contents(C:\Users\my_user\Desktop\my_project
name\storage\framework/sessions/DpZjS9gGbWcX1jfqlu4btBLD02ZaRMU58uzgIbgX):
failed to open
```

```
public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false)
    {
        return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock =false);
        // return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_EX : 0);
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you've hardcoded the sessions location/storage path unless you legitimately are uploading your website  to path `C:\Users\my_user\Desktop\my_project_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a permission issue with your storage folder. The laravel documentation states:

> Directory Permissions
> After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories >within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your >web server or Laravel will not run.

So try running the following on the server where you uploaded the code:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /storage
sudo chmod -R 755 /bootstrap/cache
```

Since you are running cpanel, instead of running these commands in the terminal, you can use these [CPanel Instructions](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/change-permissions/) for updating your folder permissions.

Comment: I tried to run this command on cpanel terminal but the result is command not found

Comment: What kind of server are you running this on? Where are you hosting it?

Comment: I went ahead and updated my answer with a link for updating folder permissions directly in CPanel.

Comment: some local unknown shared hosting, you probably don't know

Comment: alright gotta try

Comment: ok It worked, but I change it to 777, the next problem occured is it sends me to /login page not the main page

Comment: You'll have to post the routes file for me to take a look. But you probably put the 'auth' middleware on your home route and so it's trying to authenticate the user before going to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you reset the whole project folders and files permissions to be suitable with hosting by these two terminal command

```
sudo find path/to/root -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find path/to/root -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

and then

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache/

chmod -R gu+w storage/
chmod -R guo+w storage/
```

also delete the old `config.php` file

```
bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

after the old `config.php` file deleted

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: The first 4 command lines didn't work in cpanel terminal, besides the last two

Comment: What results you get when you run the commands

Comment: Do you use Shared/VPS hosting, which hosting type you are using?

Comment: I use shared hosting, does it affects?

Comment: If you use Mac / a Linux distro like Ubuntu on your local machine you should download the project and then follow instructions in the answer, if you use Windows try to search for tools for Windows to simulate linux environment, I think this software simulate the Linux environment on Windows
https://www.cygwin.com/